# Unix Shell Script: Display custom message if given extension file not exists in directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following unix shell script, which is used to list the files in the given directory. Only we need to pass the extension of the file and script should list the file or files or display custom message.

## My try:

**Script**:

```
#!/bin/sh

FileNameWithPath=`ls home\docs\customers\*.$1 | wc -w`

if [ $FileNameWithPath -gt 0 ]
then
     ls home\docs\customes\*.$1
else
     echo "Custom Message about failure(File not found)"
fi
```

**Run**:

```
$ ./Test.sh txt
```

**Note**: The above script works fine if i give file extension which is exists but if i give some non exists file extension it will through error plus custom error message. I just want to print custom message that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single command:

```
ls home/docs/customers/*.$1 2> /dev/null || echo "Custom message about failure (File not found)"
```

The first command (the 'ls') try to list the files. If it fails, it will print an error message (suppressed by '2> /dev/null') and returns an error code. Since the exit code is different by 0, the second part (the 'echo') will be executed.

If you want to keep your code, you can drop the *ls* error redirecting *stderr* to */dev/null* in this way:

```
FileNameWithPath=`ls home\docs\customers\*.$1 2>/dev/null | wc -w`
```

Comment: Perfect! Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require use of `ls`.

You can do this with globbing itself:

```
# turn on glob failure for no matches
shopt -s failglob

# list files or a custom error message
(echo home/docs/customers/*."$1") 2>/dev/null ||
echo "Custom Message about failure"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get happens in the line where you are assigning to `FileNameWithPath`. You can suppress it by redirecting it to /dev/null. i.e. `2>/dev/null`.

It is much better (and Posix compliant) to use `$()` instead of the backtick operator, given that you started your script with `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`. You will then be portable across the modern bourne shells.
Another big win for using `$()` is that they can be nested easily, whereas you have to escape the backtick when you nest it.

As Andrea Carron points out in their answer, you can do the whole thing on one line using the `||` logical-or operator. This is a very common idiom.

On the off-chance that your MVCE refers to something more complex, I fixed it for you below.

```
#!/bin/sh

FileNameWithPath=$(ls home\docs\customers\*.$1 2>/dev/null | wc -w)

if [ $FileNameWithPath -gt 0 ]
then
     ls home\docs\customes\*.$1
else
     echo "Custom Message about failure(File not found)"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add error redirection to `null` device file in second line of your script:-

```
FileNameWithPath=`ls home\docs\customers\*.$1 2>/dev/null | wc -w`
```